# VBC.exe compilation error in IIS 7

Tags: iis, sharepoint, webforms, windows-server-2012, windows-server

We have got below error when we are accessing our ASP.NEt WebForms applications which is hosted in IIS 7 but the MVC Application is working though:

```
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe
```

we already tried restarting our server and changing app pool current user but still no good result.

Comment: you ever get a solution to this? I had to move an older Vb.net app over to Windows 2012 server and all my c# apps are working fine, bu the vb.net app ain't... Getting same error as you///

Comment: We got to solve the issue by removing the KB updates in windows update on my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok what we did is below from Microsoft:

[Known issue for security updates 3098779 and 3097997 for the .NET Framework 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 after you install the .NET Framework 4.6 on Windows 8.1, Windows RT 8.1, and Windows Server 2012 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3118750)

What we did is the solution 2 which is to remove KB3098779 and KB3097997 in the windows update in our windows 2012 server and everything's back to normal.